# How to get access to the response body of the HttpServletResponse for logging into a file

Tags: java, spring-boot, servlets

I'm currently facing an issue trying to access to the response body in **HttpServletResponse** send by my controller in postHandle method inside my interceptor extending **HandlerInterceptorAdapter** into the **postHandle** method.

The objective of this is to log some data returned by the WS call in the log file. 
I already tried to use the **ContentCachingResponseWrapper** without any success with a call to IOUtils.toString(responseWrapper.getContentAsByteArray(), "UTF-8") where responseWrapper is an ContentCachingResponseWrapper. the result is null.

i already saw some response using filters or Aspects, i would like to know if it is possible to get the response content returned by the controller into the interceptor without using them and how if it is possible.

The filter solution isn't good for me by the fact i want to launch this log procedure only on few endpoints.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`RequestBody` and `ResponseBody` can be read only once. So you should not read them in an Interceptor.
You may use `ResponseBodyAdvice` available since Spring 4.1, with which you could intercept the response body before the body is written to the client.

Please refer [Filtering responses in Spring MVC](https://sdqali.in/blog/2016/06/08/filtering-responses-in-spring-mvc/) for more